# real analysis proof ? how to prove this problem

Tags: real-analysis

we are given that $S ⊆ T ⊆ \Bbb R$ and they are u.b
prove that .$$\sup S ≤ \sup T$$

What I did :
sps. $M$ is the u.b of $T$ which means for all $x$ in $T : x≤M$
and from $S ⊆ T$ we can say that $M$ is also an u.b of $S \implies$ for all $x$ in $S : x ≤  M$

I stopped here ):
what should I do to prove it

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sup T$ is an upper bond of $S$ and since $ \sup S$ is  the least upper bound of $S$, we get $ \sup S \le \sup T.$

Comment: Of course this has been asked and answered before ...

Comment: I get it now !!! thanks